# For loop (php) that results in this: 12345678910987654321

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

My niece is trying to create one for-loop (php), that results in this:
 * 12345678910987654321

example for loop she tried:

`for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++ , $i = 10; $i <= 1; $i--) {
    echo $i . ' ';
}`

She can only use if's and elseif's. I'm not a programmer and can't really help her. Any ideas how this could be achieved in php?

Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to add a variable instead of a number, then reverse that number when $i hits 10.

```
for($i = 1, $j = 1; $i> 0; $i+=$j) // Start i  at 1, and j at 1
{ 
   echo $i; 
   if($i == 10) 
        $j = -1; // i has hit 10, so use -1 to start subtracting
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to loop up to 20, printing `$i` for the ascending part and `20 - $i` for the descending.

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 20; $i++) {
    if ($i <= 10) {
        echo $i;
    } else {
        echo 20 - $i;    
    }
}
```